# Windows Scheduled Task and Console Application

Tags: windows, console

I'm creating a simple job that I'd like to run every 60 seconds (1 minute).  Instead of approaching this using a Windows Service Installer program, I'd like to create a Console App that is run through Windows Scheduler.

What will happen if a job kicks off and it takes more than 60 seconds to process? Will a second instance of a job kick off again?  I'd like Windows to manage the job in a manner such that a second instance of a job won't kick off until the first one is complete.

Does this make sense?  Will the Windows Task Scheduler use this approach by default?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Windows will start a new instance by default; however, you can control that behavior.  In Control Panel, go to Task Scheduler.  Find any time-scheduled task and right click/Properties, then choose the Settings tab.  At the bottom, you'll see an option named "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies."  You can choose to not start a new instance, run a new instance in parallel, queue a new instance, or stop the existing instance.  You want the first choice.  The [Windows Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provides the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks Carey.  Accepted answer.  Thanks for your quick feedback!